AWS API Gateway returning 200 response code with response as <html><head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head></html>
When hitting the AWS API Gateway from postman getting 200 response code but the response message is showing as follows 400 Bad Request. Even the API gateway POST method is not configured with proxy integration.

What's behind API Gateway? Note that a 200 response from API Gateway doesn't necessarily mean that the request succeeded. Related question here. Also see here.

@jarmod There was lambda configured behind the API gateway. There is no logs getting printed in API gateway & lambda, respective to the request made.

Even added the log to be printed once the lambda handler function starts executing.

Do you have any request body validation enabled in the API Gateway ?

Yes, but this is happening intermittently @manish, after some time the same request getting succeeded with valid response content.

Do you know wether does the lambda get triggered or no? i think there an issue with your connection to the Lambda

Enable and review API Gateway execution logs.
